# Wide repeated data frame to long data frame.

Tags: r

Im trying to convert a csv file that is currently in the format,

Name_A,Name_B,Value_A,Value_B,Name_A,Name_B,Value_A,Value_B..... which repeats around 50 times.

When reading the data in R converts the duplicated column names like so

Name_A,Name_B,Value_A,Value_B,Name_A_1,Name_B_1,Value_A_1,Value_B_1

I want it to be in a neat long format instead but can't figure out how. I have tried reshape and tidyr to no avail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reshaping data.frame from wide to long format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format)

Comment: Some inspiration: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41728439/tidy-data-frame-with-repeated-column-names

Comment: What is the desired output? Long or pretty (duplicated) column names or both?

Answer (score 0):

The OP didn't specify the expected result, so we have *to guess wildly* what the expected result should look like. Two possibilities are considered:

**Case 1**

```
Name_A, Value_A,
Name_B, Value_B,
Name_A, Value_A,
Name_B, Value_B,
...
```

**Case 2**

```
Name_A, Name_B, Value_A, Value_B
Name_A, Name_B, Value_A, Value_B
Name_A, Name_B, Value_A, Value_B
...
```

Both cases can be handled by `melt()` from the `data.table` package.

## Case 1

```
library(data.table)
# read csv file
wide <- fread("wide.csv")
wide
#   Name_A Name_B Value_A Value_B Name_A Name_B Value_A Value_B
#1:     A1     B1     1.1     1.2     A2     B2     2.1     2.2
#2:     C1     D1     3.1     3.2     C2     D2     4.1     4.2

# reshape
long <- melt(wide, measure.vars = patterns("^Name_", "^Value_"), 
             value.name = c("Name", "Value"), variable.name = "col_group")
long
#   col_group Name Value
#1:         1   A1   1.1
#2:         1   C1   3.1
#3:         2   B1   1.2
#4:         2   D1   3.2
#5:         3   A2   2.1
#6:         3   C2   4.1
#7:         4   B2   2.2
#8:         4   D2   4.2
```

Note that the repetitions of the name-value-pairs in each row are counted in `col_group`.

#### Input data

Since the OP didn't provide a sample data file, a data file named `"wide.csv"` was created with the following contents:

```
Name_A, Name_B, Value_A, Value_B, Name_A, Name_B, Value_A, Value_B
A1, B1, 1.1, 1.2, A2, B2, 2.1, 2.2
C1, D1, 3.1, 3.2, C2, D2, 4.1, 4.2
```

#### Adding row numbers

Row numbers can be added in two different ways.

The first variant adds row numbers to `wide` *before* melting:

```
long <- melt(wide[, rn := seq_len(.N)], measure.vars = patterns("^Name_", "^Value_"), 
             value.name = c("Name", "Value"), variable.name = "col_group")
long[order(rn)]
#   rn col_group Name Value
#1:  1         1   A1   1.1
#2:  1         2   B1   1.2
#3:  1         3   A2   2.1
#4:  1         4   B2   2.2
#5:  2         1   C1   3.1
#6:  2         2   D1   3.2
#7:  2         3   C2   4.1
#8:  2         4   D2   4.2
```

The second variant adds row numbers to `long` *after* melting using the `rowid()` function:

```
long <- melt(wide, measure.vars = patterns("^Name_", "^Value_"), 
             value.name = c("Name", "Value"), variable.name = "col_group")
long[, rn := rowid(col_group)]
long[order(rn)]
#   col_group Name Value rn
#1:         1   A1   1.1  1
#2:         2   B1   1.2  1
#3:         3   A2   2.1  1
#4:         4   B2   2.2  1
#5:         1   C1   3.1  2
#6:         2   D1   3.2  2
#7:         3   C2   4.1  2
#8:         4   D2   4.2  2
```

## Case 2

```
cols <- c("Name_A", "Name_B", "Value_A", "Value_B")
long <- melt(wide[, rn := seq_len(.N)], measure.vars = patterns(cols), 
             value.name = cols, variable.name = "col_group")
long[order(rn)]
#   rn col_group Name_A Name_B Value_A Value_B
#1:  1         1     A1     B1     1.1     1.2
#2:  1         2     A2     B2     2.1     2.2
#3:  2         1     C1     D1     3.1     3.2
#4:  2         2     C2     D2     4.1     4.2
```

Here, `col_group` counts the repetitions of *quadruples* in each row.